# Google Sheets Formula development

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have tried the same idea multiple ways and have now idea why I keep getting a formula parse error. It's probably incredibly simple. B column is populated with Y or N and I want the next column to be the antithesis.

`= IF ( B2, 'N', 'Y')`

Comment: `=IF(B2="Y","N","Y")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="Y"; "N"; "Y"))
```

Answer (score 1):

@BigBen comment is the correct answer.

You are using `IF(B2, condition if true, condition if false)`. In your case you are checking if `B2 = TRUE`

You have to check if `B2 = "Y"` and that is @BigBen comment:

`=IF(B2="Y","N","Y")`

You can check how this and all the other Sheet Functions work at the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)

Comment: This was the first solution I tried. Not sure why it didn't work)